# What would be the possible cause of an IE extension not loading?

Tags: internet-explorer, dll

I have created a simple IE extension.  When I run regasm it successfully registers and when I go into "manage add-ons", there it is.

BUT, when I try to put it on someone else's PC, it successfully registers but does not show up when I go into manage add-ons.

I can only get it to work on my PC.

I'm running windows 8.1.  It has been tried on another similar 8.1 setup.

It has been compiled to .NET 4.0 which is on the other PCs.

I have tried emptying my PATH variable to see if that made a difference and it still worked on mine.

I have installed VS on the target PC and compiled it on there.

Every time it registers fine appears in regedit, but not in IE add-on manager.

I'm using IE 11.

Any ideas anybody?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doh - figured it out in the end.  There was another registry entry that needed to be added manually:

On 32 bit windows:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\explorer\Browser Helper Objects
```

On 64 bit windows:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Browser Helper Objects
```